# Generalizing two functions which act inversely on two properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these two functions, and I feel there must be an elegant functional way to generalize them.

```
$scope.togglePick = function(){
  let targetPhoto = $scope.photoImport.data[indexService.current];
    targetPhoto.pick = !targetPhoto.pick;
    if(targetPhoto.reject && targetPhoto.pick) {
      targetPhoto.reject = false;
    }
}

$scope.toggleReject = function() {
  let targetPhoto = $scope.photoImport.data[indexService.current];
    targetPhoto.reject = !targetPhoto.reject;
    if (targetPhoto.reject && targetPhoto.pick) {
      targetPhoto.pick = false;
    }
}
```

I suppose I could pass in string params `togglePick = toggle('pick', 'reject')` and use `[]` notation in the `toggle` function, but this feels like magic strings... even though they're property names, I'm uncertain. I could also have:

```
function toggle(magicFlag){
  let primary = magicFlag ? 'pick' : 'reject';
  let secondary = magicFlag ? 'reject' : 'pick';
  ...
  targetPhoto[primary] = !targetPhoto[primary];
  ...
}
```

Again, ick, magic flag. Is there a more elegant way to do this than longhand in each function?

Comment: I think the amount of code in these functions and the slight differences makes them fine the way they are. Without working the property string weirdness, I don't see how you really make this generic _while remaining readable_. Sometimes it's okay not to be the most generic you possibly can. That line in the sand has to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: Much appreciated. I'll stick with readable. If this doesn't render this a 'non-answerable' question on SO (opinion based), I'd be happy to accept this as the answer.

Comment: Cool. I moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of code in these functions and the slight differences makes them fine the way they are. Without working the property string weirdness, I don't see how you really make this generic *while remaining readable*. Sometimes it's okay not to have the most generic code you possibly can. That line in the sand has to be drawn somewhere.